# Pass along variables between different functions

Tags: jquery, function, variables, scope

So I was trying to figure this out for hours and hours! I'm trying to make  a universal function where if the content is only a certain height, and if the user clicks on "show more", it will reveal the entire content by setting the height to auto. The problem is I'm using `.toggle()` and it needs two different functions. I want to somehow store the original value of the height, change its height to auto, and then restore its original height when the user clicks show/hide. There will be different divs in the page so ill need to make sure that when the user clicks show/hide, it will refer to the closest div.

I trying using `.data()` to pass along the same information across two seperate functions  and somehow it did work the first time i did it, but i dont know what happen and the value  stored in `.data` can't be passed along the other function.

Here's the code:

```
    // When the user clicks the button with the class .more
    $('.more').toggle(

    //This stores the height of the original div and then sets it height to auto
    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // This will travel up to the parent and find the corrresponding content div and store its height in a variable oh(original height)
        var oh = $(this).parents('.parent')
            .find('.content').height();

        // im trying to get this information to be pass along the other function
        $(this).data('original_height', oh);


        $(this).$(this).parents('.parent')
            .find('.content')
            .css('height', 'auto');
        $(this).text('hide');
    },

        // This function restores the original height of the div 
    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // im trying to get the value of the original_height to be pass along into this function. Howw!!!! 
        var original_height_value = $(this).data('original_height')

        $(this).parents('.' + parent)
            .find('.' + content)
            .css('height', original_height_value + 'px');
        $(this).text('more');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data()` part of the code seems fine to me.  What I don't understand are these two lines:

```
    $(this).$(this).parents('.parent').find('.content').css('height','auto');
```

and

```
    $(this).parents('.'+ parent).find('.' + content).css('height', original_height_value + 'px');
```

What is in the variables `parent` and `content`?

Shouldn't these two lines look for the same thing?

Also, I don't know why you would ever use `$(this).$(this)`, `$(this)` should be fine by itself.

Comment: `$(this).$(this)` should throw an error (unless a plug-in is used which adds a `$` method).

Comment: Forgot to tell you guys, this is part of a bigger function where parent and content are parameters already set. So dont worry about them, The parent is the div element holding both the button and the content, the content is simple the div thats height is being restricted. Oh and $(this).$(this) shouldnt have been there , my bad.

Comment: i used an alert() to check, the         $(this).data('original_height')
in the second function is "null" . WHYYYYYYYY!!!!!!1

Answer (score 0):

Toggle doesn't accept two functions, only a callback function:
[api.jquery.com/toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle)

Seeing your comment for Hogan:
In the first function the `oh` has the correct value?

Comment: Yes thats the weird part, i used alert, it tells me that the first function has the correct value, and the second one suddenly becomes null!!! What the heck!!!!